# matlab : why the loop return the only the last element

Tags: matlab

MatLab:
this code retrieve the words of some page and store them into wrd ,and the rows from the DB stored into kwres , and then compare them together , and return the words of like .

why this code return only the last element of the array ?

```
%connection to DB
con=database('Dic','','');
%retrieve kw_table rows (id,keywords)
kwres=fetch(con,'select * from kw_table');

[FileName,PathName]= uigetfile('*.txt');
dat= [PathName FileName];
txt=fileread(dat);
txt(~ismember(txt,['A':'Z' 'a':'z']))=' ';
wrd=strread(txt,'%s','delimiter',' ');

k=1;
for i=1:length(wrd)
s=wrd{i};
for j=1:length(kwres)
    if strcmpi(s,kwres(j,2))
        ids{k}=kwres(j,1);
        set(handles.listbox2,'String',s)
        k=k+1;
    end
end
```

end

Comment: That code doesn't "return" anything.  What variable are you talking about having only the last element?

Comment: what is `numel(txt)`?  What is `numel(wrd)`?  What is `numel(kwres)`?  And what is `k`?

Comment: sorry , i dont understand what you mean  ??? ..

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
set(handles.listbox2,'String',s)
```

you specify string in `s` to be displayed, so you end up showing last one found (actually all are displayed, but overwriting each other as `for` loop progresses).
You should be creating a list and dynamically add each string that matches to that list. Instead of `s`, the list should be in the argument of the `set` command.

Please check details at [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/306787) how to do that.